# How to fetch data once that will be used by all Reactjs Components

Tags: reactjs

I'm a beginner and read many example of how to `fetch` remote data in `Components` typically in the `componentDidMount`life cycle method.

I have 7 Components that all use the same data a json file. I dont want to fetch this data in all of the Components. Is there some method of doing this before the app start so to speak? and store the data globaly

Comment: You can make use of some state management library for that like redux or context. Once data is fetched store those in your global store and access those in your other components
Here is the link for react-redux basic tutorial
https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/basic-tutorial

Comment: Thanks the redux-saga looks perfect

Answer (score 2):

One option is to fetch the data just once in the topmost component, then pass it as props to each child (recursively, if needed). Using hooks:

```
const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    api().then((result) => {
      setData(result);
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <Component1 data={data} />
      <Component2 data={data} />
      <Component3 data={data} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

You could also fetch the data before the initial `ReactDOM.render`, and pass the data as a prop to the top component.

You can also use `useContext` to avoid having to manually pass `data` everywhere:

```
const GlobalContext = createContext();
const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    api().then((result) => {
      setData(result);
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider value={data}>
      <div>
        <Component1 />
        <Component2 />
        <Component3 />
      </div>
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
  );
};
const Component1 = () => {
  const data = useContext(GlobalContext);
  // use data
};
```

Comment: Thanks I like the "before" `ReactDOM.render` approach and asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63585983/how-is-this-specific-reactjs-code-executed-beginner-question) about it. This might be what you suggested. I ask some beginner questions about it