# How is this specific ReactJs code executed beginner question?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a beginner and are reading lots of code and now I wonder about the below code
I understand what this code is doing what I need clarification on is the code flow.

I see images loading when I run it:

1. Is React executing the code from top to bottom?
2. The PlaceholderImages async get's the images right but will `App` Component start to render with out images if it takes time? If so I dont see any `setState` that will notify `App`. I probably get it wrong!

This code is from this [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/o4joypm7j6?file=/src/index.js:1202-1207).

This is index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Masonry from "./Masonry";
import VerticalMasonry from "./VerticalMasonry";
import { sample, uniqueId } from "lodash";
import PlaceholderImages from "./PlaceholderImages";
import ItemRenderer from "./ItemRenderer";

PlaceholderImages().then(images => {
  function addItems(amount = 10) {
    return new Array(amount).fill("").map(i => {
      const id = uniqueId();
      const image = sample(images);

      const width = 480;
      const height = Math.round((480 / image.width) * image.height);
      const imageUrl = `https://picsum.photos/${width}/${height}?image=${
        image.id
      }`;

      return {
        id,
        key: id,
        ratio: 1 / (image.width / image.height),
        backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})`,
        background: `rgb(${Math.ceil(Math.random() * 256)}, ${Math.ceil(
          Math.random() * 256
        )}, ${Math.ceil(Math.random() * 256)})`,
        title: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        description:
          "At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
      };
    });
  }

  let Items = addItems();

  class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
      columns: 3,
      items: Items,
      gutter: 16,
      outerGutter: true,
      debug: true,
      vertical: true
    };

    addItems() {
      this.setState({
        items: this.state.items.concat(addItems(20))
      });
    }

    render() {
      const {
        items,
        width,
        gutter,
        outerGutter,
        debug,
        vertical,
        fullscreen
      } = this.state;

      const LeComponent = vertical ? Masonry : VerticalMasonry;

      return (
        <div>
          <div
            style={{
              position: fullscreen && "absolute",
              zIndex: 2
            }}
          >
            <label htmlFor="gutter">Gutter</label>
            <input
              id="gutter"
              type="number"
              step={1}
              min={0}
              max={32}
              value={gutter}
              onChange={e => {
                this.setState({
                  gutter: parseInt(e.target.value)
                });
              }}
            />
            <button
              onClick={() => this.setState({ outerGutter: !outerGutter })}
            >
              Outer Gutter: {outerGutter ? "On" : "Off"}
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({ debug: !debug })}>
              debug
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({ vertical: !vertical })}>
              {vertical ? "Vertical" : "Horizontal"}
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({ width: 360 })}>360</button>
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({ width: 480 })}>480</button>
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({ width: 640 })}>640</button>
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({ width: 728 })}>728</button>
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({ width: 960 })}>960</button>
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({ width: "100%" })}>
              100%
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({ fullscreen: !fullscreen })}>
              {fullscreen ? "Fullscreen off" : "Fullscreen on"}
            </button>
          </div>
          <div
            style={{
              width,
              height: !fullscreen && 600,
              position: fullscreen ? "initial" : "relative",
              margin: "0 auto"
            }}
          >
            <LeComponent
              infinite
              items={items}
              itemRenderer={ItemRenderer}
              gutter={gutter}
              outerGutter={outerGutter}
              extraPx={0}
              debug={debug}
              rows={{
                0: 1,
                320: 2,
                480: 3,
                640: 4
              }}
              cols={{
                0: 1,
                360: 2,
                640: 2,
                960: 3,
                1280: 4,
                1400: 5,
                1720: 6,
                2040: 7,
                2360: 8
              }}
              onEnd={() => {
                this.addItems();
              }}
            />
            <style>
              {`body {
                background-color:  white;
              }`}
            </style>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
});
```

This is the PlaceholderImages.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import { sampleSize } from "lodash";

export default async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.get("https://picsum.photos/list").then(res => {
      console.log(res.data[0]);
      return resolve(sampleSize(res.data, 50));
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PlaceholderImages().then(images => {...`

The first thing entering your stack here is the method `PlaceholderImages`. Thus, you should look at its code.

You will see it returns a new Promise that takes two arguments: 2 callback functions, one in case of success (resolve) and the other in case of failure (reject) of your API request. The API request happens when your perform a HTTP Request with the method GET using `axios` (a 3rd party library).

Again, you have an asynchronous function and the `.then()` method is only invoked once `axos.get()` returns something. If it never returns anything, you will never execute the `then()` function.

At this point, your stack (LIFO service discipline) will have the following methods to execute:

PlaceholderImages() -> anonymous function()* ->  new Promise() -> axios.get();

`PlaceholderImages()` won't be executed until all the other methods are executed. If the `axios.get()` method fails to gather the desired data, once you are back to the `PlaceholderImages().then()` part of the code, you won't have any images to render. Thus, nothing will be rendered anyway.

Comment: but the `PlaceholderImages()` has `{}` surrounding it encapsulating everything even the `App` that was confusing like, when would `App` be executed

Comment: The { } that you mention are for declaring the body of the function:

PlaceholderImages().then(images => {
          Function BODY 
}

images => represents an anonymous function with images as its parameter, which will return something.
Maybe reading about functions, arrow functions, and lambda functions will be helpful! I'm fighting with that too, myself!